# Java regex for google maps url?

Tags: java, regex, google-maps

I want to parse all google map links inside a String. The format is as follows :

1st example
`https://www.google.com/maps/place/white+house/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89b7b7bcdecbb1df:0x715969d86d0b76bf!8m2!3d38.8976763!4d-77.0365298`

`https://www.google.com/maps/place/white+house/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z`

`https://www.google.com/maps/place//@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z`

`https://maps.google.com/maps/place//@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z`

`https://www.google.com/maps/place/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z`

`https://google.com/maps/place/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z`

`http://google.com/maps/place/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z`

`https://www.google.com.tw/maps/place/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z`

These are all valid google map URLs (linking to White House)

Here is what I tried

```
String gmapLinkRegex = "(http|https)://(www\\.)?google\\.com(\\.\\w*)?/maps/(place/.*)?@(.*z)[^ ]*";
Pattern patternGmapLink = Pattern.compile(gmapLinkRegex , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = patternGmapLink.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  logger.info("group0 = {}" , m.group(0));
  String place = m.group(4); 
  place = StringUtils.stripEnd(place , "/"); // remove tailing '/'
  place = StringUtils.stripStart(place , "place/"); // remove header 'place/'
  logger.info("place = '{}'" , place);
  String latLngZ = m.group(5);
  logger.info("latLngZ = '{}'" , latLngZ);
}
```

It works in simple situation , but still buggy ...
for example

It need post-process to grab optional `place` information

And it cannot extract one line with two urls such as :

```
s = "https://www.google.com/maps/place//@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z " +
      " and http://google.com/maps/place/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z";
```

It should be two urls , but the regex matches the whole line ...

The points :

- The whole URL should be matched in `group(0)` (including the tailing `data` part in 1st example),
- in the 1st example , if the zoom level : `17z` is removed , it is still a valid gmap URL , but my regex cannot match it.
- Easier to extract optional `place` info
- Lat / Lng extraction is must , zoom level is optional.
- Able to parse multiple urls in one line
- Able to process `maps.google.com(.xx)/maps` , I tried `(www|maps\.)?` but seems still buggy

Any suggestion to improve this regex ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: I think if you remove `[^ ]*` from the very end, it would already be an improvement. All your examples end with `[\d]z`, what's that part for?

Comment: `z` means zoom level , sometimes it is mandatory , sometimes it is optional. In the first example (with tailing `data` part) it is optional , but it seems in other examples , `z` is mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot-asterisk

```
.*
```

will always allow anything to the end of the last url.
You need "tighter" regexes, which match a single URL but not several with anything in between.
The "[^ ]*" might include the next URL if it is separated by something other than " ", which includes line break, tab, shift-space...

I propose (sorry, not tested on java), to use "anything but @" and "digit, minus, comma or dot" and "optional special string followed by tailored charset, many times".

```
"(http|https)://(www\.)?google\.com(\.\w*)?/maps/(place/[^@]*)?@([0123456789\.,-]*z)(\/data=[\!:\.\-0123456789abcdefmsx]+)?"
```

I tested the one above on a perl-regex compatible engine (np++).
Please adapt yourself, if I guessed anything wrong. The explicit list of digits can probably be replaced by "\d", I tried to minimise assumptions on regex flavor.

In order to match "URL" or "URL and URL", please use a variable storing the regex, then do "(URL and )*URL", replacing "URL" with regex var. (Asuming this is possible in java.) If the question is how to then retrieve the multiple matches: That is java, I cannot help. Let me know and I delete this answer, not to provoke deserved downvotes ;-)

(Edited to catch the data part in, previously not seen, first example, first line; and the multi URLs in one line.)

Comment: Hi it matches multiple urls in one line, but it cannot match the `data` part of the example 1. ( and the last part is `[^\\W]*` I think) , if `[^\\w]*` , it cannot match multiple urls in one line.

Comment: So it should catch multiple URLs? I misundestood that. And my "bio-visual" regex missed the whole first example when copying it to test input. I will be back.

Comment: The (now anyway completely different) last part was total bogus, not related to "anything but whitespace", which would be "[^\s]". It wrongly was "anything but identifier-like character". Forget it. Only by chance it did something useful by chance. If you test (in-)appropriatly, any error can remain unspotted.

Comment: `"(http|https)://(www\\.)?google\\.com(\\.\\w*)?/maps/(place/[^@]*)?@([0-9.,-]*z)(/data=[!:.\\-0-9a-fmsx]+)?"`  Thanks , it almost works , except the `place` still need to be post-processed.

Comment: @smallfu If you define some requirements for the place thing (java is not my thing) I might add something to simply capture it surgically from regex.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this regex to validate google maps links:

```
"(http:|https:)?\\/\\/(www\\.)?(maps.)?google\\.[a-z.]+\\/maps/?([\\?]|place/*[^@]*)?/*@?(ll=)?(q=)?(([\\?=]?[a-zA-Z]*[+]?)*/?@{0,1})?([0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]+(,|&[a-zA-Z]+=)-?[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]+(,?[0-9]+(z|m))?)?(\\/?data=[\\!:\\.\\-0123456789abcdefmsx]+)?"
```

I tested with the following list of google maps links:

```
String location1 = "http://www.google.com/maps/place/21.01196755,105.86306012";
String location2 = "https://www.google.com.tw/maps/place/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z";
String location3 = "http://www.google.com/maps/place/21.01196755,105.86306012";
String location4 = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/white+house/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89b7b7bcdecbb1df:0x715969d86d0b76bf!8m2!3d38.8976763!4d-77.0365298";
String location5 = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/white+house/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z";
String location6 = "https://www.google.com/maps/place//@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z";
String location7 = "https://maps.google.com/maps/place//@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z";
String location8 = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z";
String location9 = "https://google.com/maps/place/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z";
String location10 = "http://google.com/maps/place/@38.8976763,-77.0387185,17z";
String location11 = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/@/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x3135abf74b040853:0x6ff9dfeb960ec979";
String location12 = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=New+York,+NY,+USA&hl=no&sll=19.808054,-63.720703&sspn=54.337928,93.076172&oq=n&hnear=New+York&t=m&z=10";
String location13 = "https://www.google.com/maps";
String location14 = "https://www.google.fr/maps";
String location15 = "https://google.fr/maps";
String location16 = "http://google.fr/maps";
String location17 = "https://www.google.de/maps";
String location18 = "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4";
String location19 = "https://www.google.de/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4";
String location20 = "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4&layer=t&lci=com.panoramio.all,com.google.webcams,weather";
String location21 = "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.370157,0.615234&spn=45.047033,93.076172&t=m&z=4&layer=t";
String location22 = "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4";
String location23 = "https://www.google.de/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4";
String location24 = "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=45.197878,93.076172&t=h&z=4&layer=t&lci=com.panoramio.all,com.google.webcams,weather";
String location25 = "https://www.google.com/maps?ll=37.370157,0.615234&spn=45.047033,93.076172&t=m&z=4&layer=t";
String location26 = "http://www.google.com/maps/place/21.01196755,105.86306012";
String location27 = "http://google.com/maps/bylatlng?lat=21.01196022&lng=105.86298748";
String location28 = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/C%C3%B4ng+vi%C3%AAn+Th%E1%BB%91ng+Nh%E1%BA%A5t,+354A+%C4%90%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Dng+L%C3%AA+Du%E1%BA%A9n,+L%C3%AA+%C4%90%E1%BA%A1i+H%C3%A0nh,+%C4%90%E1%BB%91ng+%C4%90a,+H%C3%A0+N%E1%BB%99i+100000,+Vi%E1%BB%87t+Nam/@21.0121535,105.8443773,13z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x3135ab8ee6df247f:0xe6183d662696d2e9";
```

Comment: Regex contain parse error